# Passing the input value of prompt boxes

Tags: javascript, input, popup, prompt

Is it possible to pass a input value of prompt box like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function prompt_box()
{
var naam=prompt("Please enter your name:","Type your name here.")
document.location = 'delete.php?target=' + naam;
}
</script>
```

Or do I have to use a form?

Comment: What do you mean by "this"? That code works fine for me.

Comment: pop-up can be intrusive for User experience... but hell it would work!

Comment: Have you even tried it yourself to see if it works? The answer is yes however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the correct way of passing the value returned from `prompt` to a variable.

```
var value = prompt("Please enter your name:", "Type your name here.");
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I think there was something wrong with parsing in my initial code. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a window prompt using javascript it will ask you to input something. So you have to implement your code in this way to get the prompt,

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var name = prompt("Please enter your name", "Micheal");
  if (name != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    "Hello " + name + "! How are you today?";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```